# Mutate a Couchbase Sub document using Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase

Trying to mutate sub document by appending a value in Couchbase through Spring data. But it fails:

//Sample Document

`{
"type": "account",
  "events": [
    {
      "transactionReference": "",
      "value": 100
    }
   ]
}`

Objective is to add one more entry in the event array. Below is the snippet which is performing operation.

`Event eventObj = new Event(...);
  repository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket()
            .mutateIn("doc_id")
            .arrayPrepend("events", eventObj,false).execute();`

**Update**
execute() method was missing earlier. 
Below is the stack trace of the exception

`com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: FAILURE
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.SubdocHelper.commonSubdocErrors(SubdocHelper.java:95)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncMutateInBuilder$12.call(AsyncMutateInBuilder.java:923)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncMutateInBuilder$12.call(AsyncMutateInBuilder.java:917)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncMutateInBuilder$17.call(AsyncMutateInBuilder.java:1010)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.AsyncMutateInBuilder$17.call(AsyncMutateInBuilder.java:1000)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:106)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:375)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:69)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:393)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.core.message.kv.subdoc.simple.SimpleSubdocResponse.class`

Comment: What Couchbase client and server versions are you using? The FAILURE status is for errors not expected by the JAVA SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The [Couchbase Sub-Document API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/developer-guide/sub-doc-api.html) is a builder API that allows you to chain together multiple mutate commands (or multiple retrieval commands).  With the [Java SDK](https://blog.couchbase.com/subdocument-couchbase-java-sdk/#toc_3) you must call `execute()` to perform those mutations.

```
Event eventObj = new Event(...);
repository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket()
        .mutateIn("doc_id")
        .arrayPrepend("events", eventObj,false)
        .execute();
```

Comment: My bad @Jeff for the typo, mutate method doesn't exist. I have corrected the snippet.